# JavaFx 2 - TableView , return selected item

Tags: javafx-2, tableview

I would like to get the selected item as String from a TableView, but it returns the whole path.

[image]

In the picture above, when I click to select the cell, I would like to get

```
Indicator selected is: = Shannon Entropy;
```

while I get

```
Indicator selected is: taindicators.indicatorsmaingui.IndicatorsGuiController$Indicators@2dafcbf
```

Here is my code

```
tableviewIndicators.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override 
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown() && event.getClickCount() == 1) {

                String indSelected = tableviewIndicators.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
                System.out.println("Indicator selected is: " + indSelected);                   
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you implement `toString`?

Comment: String indSelected = tableviewIndicators.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: I mean overrider `toString` in the class that represent the `TableView` row.

Comment: Best way would be to use ChangeListener instead of Mouse handler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, it would be better to use `ChangeListener` for `TableView` instead of `EventHandler<MouseEvent>`. Here is a small demo:

**EDIT: Java 8**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TableDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Label lblTool = new Label();


        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5.0);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        hBox.getChildren().add(lblTool);


        final TableView<TableProps> table = new TableView<>();

        //Table columns
        TableColumn<TableProps, String> clmTool = new TableColumn<>("Tool");
        clmTool.setMinWidth(160);
        clmTool.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tool"));

        TableColumn<TableProps, String> clmChart = new TableColumn<>("Chart");
        clmChart.setMinWidth(160);
        clmChart.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("chart"));

        //Add data
        final ObservableList<TableProps> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new TableProps("Volume", ""),
                new TableProps("Shannon entropy", "")
        );
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(clmTool, clmChart);

        //Add change listener
        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
            if (table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                lblTool.setText(newValue.getTool());
            }
        });

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(hBox);
        pane.setCenter(table);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 640, 480));
        stage.show();

    }

    public class TableProps {
        private final SimpleStringProperty tool;
        private final SimpleStringProperty chart;

        public TableProps(String tool, String chart) {
            this.tool = new SimpleStringProperty(tool);
            this.chart = new SimpleStringProperty(chart);
        }

        public String getTool() {
            return tool.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty toolProperty() {
            return tool;
        }

        public void setTool(String tool) {
            this.tool.set(tool);
        }

        public String getChart() {
            return chart.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty chartProperty() {
            return chart;
        }

        public void setChart(String chart) {
            this.chart.set(chart);
        }
    }

}
```

You may also notice that it works even when you move arrow keys. Not just by mouse click.

Comment: @Reegan It's a demo for Christ sake. I won't rebuild his whole application. And it answers his question how to select string items. He won't return string value from check box.

Comment: I have a simple TableCellCheckBox demo sample code is there i think this is useful for @Alberto acepsut i will post that sample code....

Comment: Thank you brano88 and Reegan for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

```
package tablecellfactorysample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author reegan
 */
public class TableCellFactorySample extends Application {

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person(true, "Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person(false, "Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person(true, "Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person(true, "Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person(true, "Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person(false, "Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));

        //"Invited" column

        TableColumn invitedCol = new TableColumn<Person, Boolean>();

        invitedCol.setText("Invited");

        invitedCol.setMinWidth(50);

        invitedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("invited"));

        invitedCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Boolean>, TableCell<Person, Boolean>>() {
            public TableCell<Person, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Person, Boolean> p) {

                return new CheckBoxTableCell<Person, Boolean>();

            }
        });

        //"First Name" column

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn();

        firstNameCol.setText("First");

        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));

        //"Last Name" column

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn();

        lastNameCol.setText("Last");

        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));

        //"Email" column

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn();

        emailCol.setText("Email");

        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);

        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("email"));



        //Set cell factory for cells that allow editing

        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory =
                new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {

                return new EditingCell();

            }
        };

        emailCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);



        //Set handler to update ObservableList properties. Applicable if cell is edited

        updateObservableListProperties(emailCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol);



        TableView tableView = new TableView();

        tableView.setItems(data);

        //Enabling editing

        VBox vb = new VBox();

        tableView.setEditable(true);

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(invitedCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);


        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("Select all");
        cb.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
                    Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
                if (new_val) {
                    for (Person p : data) {
                        p.invited.set(true);
                    }

                }


            }
        });


        vb.getChildren().addAll(cb, tableView);
        root.getChildren().addAll(vb);

    }

    private void updateObservableListProperties(TableColumn emailCol, TableColumn firstNameCol,
            TableColumn lastNameCol) {

        //Modifying the email property in the ObservableList

        emailCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {

                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEmail(t.getNewValue());

            }
        });

        //Modifying the firstName property in the ObservableList

        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {

                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());

            }
        });

        //Modifying the lastName property in the ObservableList

        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {

                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setLastName(t.getNewValue());

            }
        });

    }

    //Person object
    public static class Person {

        private BooleanProperty invited;
        private StringProperty firstName;
        private StringProperty lastName;
        private StringProperty email;

        private Person(boolean invited, String fName, String lName, String email) {

            this.invited = new SimpleBooleanProperty(invited);

            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);

            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);

            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);

            this.invited = new SimpleBooleanProperty(invited);



            this.invited.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {

                    System.out.println(firstNameProperty().get() + " invited: " + t1);

                }
            });

        }

        public BooleanProperty invitedProperty() {
            return invited;
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email.set(email);
        }
    }

    //CheckBoxTableCell for creating a CheckBox in a table cell
    public static class CheckBoxTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

        private final CheckBox checkBox;
        private ObservableValue<T> ov;

        public CheckBoxTableCell() {

            this.checkBox = new CheckBox();

            this.checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);



            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            setGraphic(checkBox);

        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {

                setText(null);

                setGraphic(null);

            } else {

                setGraphic(checkBox);

                if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {

                    checkBox.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional((BooleanProperty) ov);

                }

                ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());

                if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {

                    checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional((BooleanProperty) ov);

                }

            }

        }
    }

    // EditingCell - for editing capability in a TableCell
    public static class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

        private TextField textField;

        public EditingCell() {
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {

            super.startEdit();



            if (textField == null) {

                createTextField();

            }

            setText(null);

            setGraphic(textField);

            textField.selectAll();

        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {

            super.cancelEdit();

            setText((String) getItem());

            setGraphic(null);

        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {

                setText(null);

                setGraphic(null);

            } else {

                if (isEditing()) {

                    if (textField != null) {

                        textField.setText(getString());

                    }

                    setText(null);

                    setGraphic(textField);

                } else {

                    setText(getString());

                    setGraphic(null);

                }

            }

        }

        private void createTextField() {

            textField = new TextField(getString());

            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);

            textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent t) {

                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

                        commitEdit(textField.getText());

                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {

                        cancelEdit();

                    }

                }
            });

        }

        private String getString() {

            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        init(primaryStage);

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```