# javafx 2 CheckBoxTableCell not working in tableview

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx-2, tableview, javafx-8

I need some help, even my case is simple. 
But i can't understand why the check box in the tableview is not geting the value.
I have get the example from the javafx ensemble

I have a class

```
public class ReservationObj {
    private  BooleanProperty        tcheck;        
    private  StringProperty         tname;      
    private  StringProperty         tstatus;       
    private  int                    tser;

    public ReservationObj(boolean tcheck, String lname , String lBStatus, int serialinVector) {

        this.tcheck = new SimpleBooleanProperty(tcheck);            
        this.tname = new SimpleStringProperty(lname); 
        this.tstatus = new SimpleStringProperty(lBStatus);  

        this.tser = serialinVector;   

        this.tcheck.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                System.out.println("The check Box is: " + t1);
            }
        });

    }

    public BooleanProperty getTcheck() {return tcheck;}

    public String   getTname() {return tname.getValue() ;}

    public void setTname(String tname) {this.tname.set(tname);}

    public String  getTstatus() {return tstatus.getValue() ;}

    public void setTstatus(String tstatus) {this.tstatus.set(tstatus);}

    public int getTser() {return tser;}

    public void setTser(int tser) { this.tser = tser;}

}
```

And also i have the.

```
public Parent createContent() {

final  ObservableList<ReservationObj> ReservationList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new ReservationObj(true, "aaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbb", 1));

    TableColumn RCheckCol = new TableColumn<ReservationObj, Boolean>();

    RCheckCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tcheck"));          
    RCheckCol.setText("aaa");        
    RCheckCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ReservationObj, Boolean>, TableCell<ReservationObj, Boolean>>() {

        public TableCell<ReservationObj, Boolean> call(TableColumn<ReservationObj, Boolean> p) {

            return new CheckBoxTableCell<ReservationObj, Boolean>();

        }
    });

    TableColumn RNameCol = new TableColumn();
    RNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tname"));        
    RNameCol.setText("bbbb");

    TableColumn RAgeCol = new TableColumn();
    RAgeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tstatus"));
    RAgeCol.setText("cccc");

    TableView AAView   = new TableView();           

    AAView.setItems(ReservationList);          
    AAView.setEditable(true);        
    AAView.getColumns().addAll(RCheckCol,RNameCol,RAgeCol);      

    return AAView;

}
```

And when simple .

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

The columns of the tableview are getting the values except from the first “Checkbox”.
Also the listener in the checkbox is not working.
I really don’t understand what I have done wrong. Because I get the example from the ensemble.
Thanks for every idea and any solution.
Elias

Comment: see this example:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374626/javafx-2-tableview-return-selected-item/18382098#18382098

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ReservationObj` class doesn’t respect [JavaFX Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm)  convention in naming methods.

If you want to bind the `RCheckCol` with the `tcheck` `BooleanProperty` in :

```
  RCheckCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tcheck"));
```

You have to provide a `tcheckProperty` method in your model class:

```
public BooleanProperty tcheckProperty() {
        return tcheck;
    }
```

---

As an example of a valid `JavaFX Bean`:

```
public class Person {

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name.setValue(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.getValue();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.setValue(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved a long standing bug in my application. Thanks!